# WinUI 3 Selected Items from ListView send with CommandParameter

Tags: xaml, listview, winui-3, multipleselection, commandparameter

I have a WinUI 3 project scaffolded with Template Studio. A ListView with Multiple selection mode. I use MVVM, so binding through commands to the view model. When I change selections inside my list, the program enters my method which is good. But my parameter is null.

How can I when I change selections inside my list to send the elements to a method inside my view model.
`CommandParameter="{Binding}"` might be the problem.

MyPage.xaml

```
<ListView
    SelectionMode="Multiple"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.ValidationFlagsList, Mode=OneTime}"
    SelectedValuePath="Key"
    DisplayMemberPath="Value">
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.FlagCheckBoxChangedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" /> 
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ListView>
```

MyViewModel.cs

```
public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> ValidationFlagsList => EnumExtensions.GetAllValuesAndDescriptions<ValidationFlag>();

public ICommand FlagCheckBoxChangedCommand { get; }

ctor() 
{
    FlagCheckBoxChangedCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(FlagCheckBox_Changed);
}


private void FlagCheckBox_Changed(object validationFlag)
{
    // Problem: method is called, but parameter is null
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove the `CommandParameter` and the `SelectionChangedEventArgs` will be passed to the command.

```xml
<ListView
    DisplayMemberPath="Value"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.ValidationFlagsList, Mode=OneTime}"
    SelectedValuePath="Key"
    SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.FlagCheckBoxChangedCommand}" />
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ListView>
```

Then in `SelectionChangedEventArgs`, you'll get `AddedItems` and `RemovedItems`.

BTW, the `ListView` **has** a `SelectedItems` property but it's just a plain property and not a `DependencyProperty`, so unfortunately you can't use it in bindings. Here's a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74779046/2411960) if you are interested.

Comment: It works now. But should I import this module in a ViewModel `using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;`? It's required for parameter SelectionChangedEventArgs. Is it relevant more to Code-Behind approach?

Comment: I don't think so. That is just namespace, not a module.